# How to implement method of type Expression<Func<T, bool>> where

Tags: boolean, expression, predicate, func

So I have a repository abstract class with a method called GetMany like this:

public virtual IEnumerable GetMany(Expression> where)

how to implement this in the derived class?

Infrastructure:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {
        #region Properties
        private ApplicationDbContext dataContext;
        private readonly IDbSet<T> dbSet;

        protected IDbFactory DbFactory
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        protected ApplicationDbContext DbContext
        {
            get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DbFactory.Init()); }
        }
        #endregion

        protected RepositoryBase(IDbFactory dbFactory)
        {
            DbFactory = dbFactory;
            dbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
        }

        #region Implementation
        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return dbSet.Where(where).ToList();
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Service:

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {
        RepositoryBase<T> GetBase<T>();
    }
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>, IRepositoryBase<AppAccessPolicy>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store)
            : base(store)
        {
            PasswordValidator = new CustomPasswordValidator();
        }

        private RepositoryBase<T> GetBase<T>()
        {
            var baseClass = GetBase<T>();
            return baseClass;
        }


        public override IEnumerable<AppInstitution> GetMany(Expression<Func<AppInstitution, bool>> where)
        {
            return dbSet.Where(where).ToList();
        } 

       . . . .
 }
```

I need to know how to properly implement this part:

**public override IEnumerable GetMany(Expression> where)
        {
            return dbSet.Where(where).ToList();
        }**

Comment: Can we see more code? What have you tried? When you say implement, do you mean against something like Entity Framework?

Comment: You have set the type parameter for the ApplicationUserManager class as AppAccessPolicy, but you're trying to use AppInstitution as the type parameter for GetMany(), is that a typo?

Comment: No, it's not....  But I think I have it now: Expression<Func<AppInstitution, bool>> where = a => a.INO != null;
                IEnumerable<AppInstitution> _iun = appInst.GetMany(where);